# Is there a list of names you should not use in programming?

Tags: programming-languages

Is there a list of items on the web that you should not use when creating a model or variable?

For example, if I wanted to create apartment listings, naming a model something like `Property` would be problematic in the future and also confusing since `property` is a built-in Python function.

I did try Googling this, but couldn't come up with anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Google for the specific language + reserved words. Searching for available operators can also be prudent as more languages are adopting specail use operators.

Comment: Very generic terms like `property`, `context`, `description`, `info`, `attribute`, are not necessary reserved but used frequently in API/framework. Try to stick names coming from the business domain of the app.

Comment: You might be interested to look at Variable Shadowing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing), and Method Overloading (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading). Both should be avoided to avoid confusions.

Comment: @ewernli, Would you like to edit your comment and add your last comment as answer? That's actually what I'm looking for. Thank you for providing this and not an explanation for why I don't need a list of confusions. I'm actually writing an app that will be passed from Python to Javascript in the views, so one function in Python may not be a function in Javascript and vice versa. I don't know why the answerers assumed I'd be writing something in one language.

Comment: @AAA Glad to hear it helped. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules and constraints about naming depend on the programming language. How an identifier/name is bound depends on the language semantics and its [scoping rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29): an identifer/name will be bound to different element depending on the scope. Scoping is usally lexical (i.e. static) but some language have dynamic scoping (some variant of lisp).

If names are different, there is no confusion in scoping. If identifiers/names are reused accrossed scopes, an identifier/name might mask another one.  This is referred as [Shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). This is a source of confusion.

Certain reserved names (i.e. keywords) have special meaning. Such keyword can simply be forbidden as names of other elements, or not.

For instance, in Smallatalk `self` is a keyword. It is still possible to declare a temporary variable `self`, though. In the scope where the temporary variable is visible, `self` resolves to the temporary variable, not the usual self that is receiver of the message.

Of course, shadowing can happen between regular names.

Scoping rules take types into consideration as well, and [inheritance might introduce shadows](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java/exp/ch05_05.htm).

Another source of confusion related to binding is [Method Overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading). In statically typed languages, which method is executed depends on the static types at the call site. In certain cases, [overloading makes it confusing to know which method is selected](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31551&seqNum=4). Both Shadowing and Overloading should avoided to avoid confusions.

If your goal is to translate Python to Javascript, and vice versa, I guess you need to check the scoping rules and keywords of both languages to make sure your translation is not only syntactically correct, but also semantically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, programming languages have 'reserved words' or 'keywords' that you're either not able to use or in some cases are but should stay away from. For Python, you can find that list [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).

Comment: I was looking more for a version that a programmer came up with that isn't "official" but is suggested. While I _could_ name a model something like Property, it would not be recommended since the lowercased property is a Python function.

Comment: @AAA: I am not sure what exactly you are asking about. What is your *actual* problem? Is it just conflicts with reserved words? Or something more than that?

Comment: @AAA: As thkala mentioned, I'd just focus on naming things in a clear and sensible way that makes sense in the context of the project.

Comment: I understand what all of you mean and that naming conflicting things already comes up with errors, but I just wanted a simple list -- something that maybe a blogger posted -- not an explanation for why I don't need a list.
 
@thkala, I'm not sure I understand what you don't understand. Say, I personally would not name an application in Django called 'property' because `property` is a Python function -- and as it stands, you _can_ name an application called property in Django. It's sort of like how you _can_ name a variable with something like `xyz`, but a variable like that lacks clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Most words in most natural languages can have different meanings, according to the *context*. That's why we use *specifiers* to make the meaning of a word clear. If in any case you think that some particular identifier may be confusing, you can just add a specifier to make it clear. For example `ObjectProperty` has probably nothing to do with real estate, even in an application that *deals* with real estate.

The case you present is no different than using generic identifiers with no attached context. For example a variable named `limit` or `length` may have completely different meanings in different programs. Just use identifiers that make sense and *document* their meaning extensively. Being consistent within your own code base would also be preferable. Do not complicate your life with banned term lists that will never be complete and will only make programming more difficult.

The obvious exceptions are words reserved by your programming language of choice - but then again no decent compiler would allow you to use them anyway...